# My Project will suddenly freeze and i am unable to stop the freeze from happening

Tags: java, swing

i have been recently working on the following, after hitting run and then going through multiple GUI's it will load onto a Panal that runs the game, the problem is, is that it isn't doing what it is supposed to do. below is the code that has been giving me troubles. i have asked my IT teacher for help he isnt sure what is going wrong either.

```
    package edge;

    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Dungeon1 extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Timer timer = new Timer(1, this);
    Player player = new Player();
    DungeonBackground db = new DungeonBackground(0, 0);
    Enemy e1 = new Enemy(200, 200);

    /**
     * Creates new form Dungeon1
     */
    public Dungeon1() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(1366, 706);
        timer.start();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        setRequestFocusEnabled(false);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/edge/Dundeon 1 - 1.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("\n");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 707, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void Paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("Dundeon 1 - 1.jpg");
        IMG = img.getImage();
        g2d.drawImage(IMG, 0, 0, null);

        if (firstform == true && secondform == false && thirdform == false) {
            ImageIcon imageIcon2 = new ImageIcon("enemy1.bmp");
            g2d.drawImage(imageIcon2.getImage(), e1.getX(), e1.getY(), this);
        } else if (secondform == true && firstform == false && thirdform == false) {
            ImageIcon imageIcon3 = new ImageIcon("enemy1-1.bmp");
            g2d.drawImage(imageIcon3.getImage(), e1.getX(), e1.getY(), this);
            secondform = false;
            thirdform = true;
            firstform = false;
        } else if (thirdform == true && firstform == false && secondform == false) {
            ImageIcon imageIcon4 = new ImageIcon("enemy1-2.bmp");
            g2d.drawImage(imageIcon4.getImage(), e1.getX(), e1.getY(), this);
            firstform = true;
            secondform = false;
            thirdform = false;
            RageGUI rg1 = new RageGUI();
            rg1.setVisible(true);
        }
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("characterfinal.jpg");
        g2d.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e1.getX() == (player.getX() + 190) && e1.getY() == player.getY()
                || e1.getY() == (player.getY() - 190) && e1.getX() == player.getX()) {
            firstform = false;
            secondform = true;
        }
        if (e1.getX() == (player.getX() - 190) && e1.getY() == player.getY()) {
            firstform = false;
            secondform = true;
        }
        if (e1.getY() == (player.getY() - 190) && e1.getX() == player.getX()) {
            firstform = false;
            secondform = true;
        }
        while (e1isalive == true) {
            double rdn = Math.random();
            if (rdn <= 0.25) {
                e1.MoveSequence1();
            }
            if (rdn <= 0.5) {
                e1.MoveSequence2();
            }
            if (rdn <= 0.75) {
                e1.MoveSequence3();
            }
            if (rdn <= 1) {
                e1.MoveSequence4();
            }

        }
        if (player.getX() == 87 && player.getY() == 81 && player.getDirection() == 4) {
            player.MoveLeft();
            player.MoveDown();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 380 && player.getY() == 500 && player.getDirection() == 4) {
            player.MoveLeft();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 91 && player.getY() == 520 && player.getDirection() == 4) {
            player.MoveLeft();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 85 && player.getY()== 355 && player.getDirection() == 4) {
            player.MoveLeft();
        } 
        if (player.getX() == 284 && player.getY() == 399 && player.getDirection() == 3) {
            player.MoveRight();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 284 && player.getY() == 399 && player.getDirection() == 1) {
            player.MoveDown();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 649 && player.getY() == 515 && player.getDirection() == 3) {
            player.MoveRight();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 811 && player.getY() == 243 && player.getDirection() == 2) {
            player.MoveUp();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 811 && player.getY() == 243 && player.getDirection() == 1) {
            player.MoveDown();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 671 && player.getY() == 365 && player.getDirection() == 4) {
            player.MoveLeft();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 940 && player.getY() == 350 && player.getDirection() == 3) {
            player.MoveLeft();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 812 && player.getY() == 513 && player.getDirection() == 1) {
            player.MoveDown();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 140 && player.getY() == 150 && player.getDirection() == 4) {
            player.MoveLeft();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 900 && player.getY() == 600 && player.getDirection() == 3 ) {
            player.MoveRight();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 1159 && player.getY() == 461 && player.getDirection() == 3 ) {
            player.MoveRight();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 660 && player.getY() == 110 && player.getDirection() == 4 ) {
            player.MoveLeft();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 995 && player.getY() == 285 && player.getDirection() == 1) {
            player.MoveDown();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 1160 && player.getY() == 120 && player.getDirection() == 3 ) {
            player.MoveRight();
        }
        if (player.getX() == 393 && player.getY() == 634 && player.getDirection() == 4) {

            System.out.println("do you want to die???"
                    + " or did you think you found a secret way out of the dungeon??"
                    + " well you are right, you win");
            RageQuitGUI rg = new RageQuitGUI() ;
            rg.setVisible(true) ;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
         if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            player.MoveUp();
            System.out.println("w key has been pressed");
        } else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            player.MoveLeft();
            System.out.println("a key has been pressed");
        } else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            player.MoveRight();
            System.out.println("d key has been pressed");
        } else if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            player.MoveDown();
            System.out.println("s key has been pressed");
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ALT + KeyEvent.VK_F4) {
            RageQuitGUI rg = new RageQuitGUI();
            rg.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

    }
    boolean e1isalive = true;
    boolean firstform = true;
    boolean secondform = false;
    boolean thirdform = false;
    Image IMG;
//  sometimes the code works and soetimes it doesnt.
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Does it always freeze after the same amount of time? Have you tried using a debugger, or even print statements, to figure out where in the code the freeze is occurring? It would help us answer your question :)

Comment: yes on multiple occasions, and always at the same moment, as this panel code is to be renderd

Comment: just to be sure i went back and checked again, the only thong that wasnt frozen was the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will fix your problem but here are some issues:

1. You are overriding the `Paint(...)` method. There is no such method. There is a lowercase `paint(...)` method. However, when using Swing you should be overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method.
2. A painting method is for just doing painting, not any other processing. You can't control when Swing will invoke the paintComponent() method, so the painting method should just paint the current state of the class, not change the state. So:

   1. Don't do I/O. The method should be efficient. You don't want to keep reading files
   2. Don't create new objects
   3. Don't change the properties of your class (ie firstForm, secondForm ...)
3. Don't use a while(...) loop for animation. The animation will occur too fast and you will only see the final result. Instead you should be using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation. I see you are using a Timer elsewhere in your code. Don't use 1ms for the Timer. The Timer is not that accurate and will generate too many events. The minimum should be around 16, that will get you 60 frames a second.